Could not solve MINLP in Gekko (Warning no more possible trial points and no integer solution) with Gekko_NN_TF as a objective function
I am very new to the Gekko Package in python. My target is to maximize 'Q_factor' from the trained TensorFlow model (.keras) I already have.
I use Gekko in Steady State Mode (m.options.IMODE=2) for parameter estimation and (m.options.SOLVER=1) with some constraints below:

** Note that

N is required to be integer between 2 and 8.
Freq is fixed to be 13.56
Do_1 and Do_2 are fixed to be 200
t1 and t2 are fixed to be 0.5 **

1. Firstly, I can solve the problem above *but the result -m.options.OBJFCNVAL didn't seem right (Too large solution). The solution pred_Q_factor is supposed to be around ~700-1000. You can see the code and the solution below:
## 1st CODE ##

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from gekko import GEKKO
from gekko.ML import Gekko_NN_TF, CustomMinMaxGekkoScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# Q-factor prediction from trained TF model
model_path = 'model_path'
model = load_model(model_path)

# CSV file reading
data_path = 'datapath'
data = pd.read_csv(data_path)

# Define output feature of the model
target = ['Q_factor']
# Basically, the input features are [Freq, Do_1, Do_2, d, p1, p2, N, w1, w2, Di_1, Di_2, t1, t2]
features = [col for col in data.columns if col not in target]

# Find max/min of scaler for Gekko_NN_TF parameters
s = CustomMinMaxGekkoScaler(data, features, target)
mma = s.minMaxValues()

# Initialize GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# Design Requirements
freq_const = 13.56
Do_const = 200
sys_thickness = 200
copper_thickness = 0.5

# Define variables with bounds
Freq = m.FV(value=freq_const, lb=1, ub=30,name='Freq')
Do_1 = m.FV(value=Do_const, lb=100, ub=200,name='Do_1')
Do_2 = m.FV(value=Do_const, lb=100, ub=200,name='Do_2')
p1 = m.Var(value=1, lb=1, ub=20,name='p1')
p2 = m.Var(value=1, lb=1, ub=20,name='p2')
t1 = m.FV(value=copper_thickness, lb=0.5, ub=2,name='t1')
t2 = m.FV(value=copper_thickness, lb=0.5, ub=2,name='t2')
d = m.Var(value=1, lb=2, ub=5,name='d')
N = m.Var(value=4, lb=2, ub=10, integer=True,name='N')
w1 = m.Var(value=13.87, lb=5, ub=50,name='w1')
w2 = m.Var(value=15.06, lb=5, ub=50,name='w2')
Di_1 = m.Var(value=50, lb=5, ub=50,name='Di_1')
Di_2 = m.Var(value=50, lb=5, ub=50,name='Di_2')


# Define constraints
m.Equation(Di_1 == Di_2)
m.Equation(Di_1 <= Do_const)
m.Equation(Di_2 <= Do_const)
m.Equation(t1 + t2 + d <= sys_thickness)
m.Equation(p1 == (Do_1 - Di_1 - (3 * np.pi * N + 4 * np.pi - 1) / (2 * np.pi) * w1) * 2 * np.pi / (3 * np.pi * N - 1))
m.Equation(p2 == (Do_2 - Di_2 - (3 * np.pi * N + 4 * np.pi - 1) / (2 * np.pi) * w2) * 2 * np.pi / (3 * np.pi * N - 1))
m.Equation(p1 <= w1)
m.Equation(p2 <= w2)
# m.Equation(resonant_freq <= (Freq+0.1*Freq)*1e6)
# m.Equation(resonant_freq >= (Freq-0.1*Freq)*1e6)

# Define all variables for prediction
variables = [Freq, Do_1, Do_2, d, p1, p2, N, w1, w2, Di_1, Di_2, t1, t2]

# Define model from Tensorflow/Keras trained model
pred_Q_factor = Gekko_NN_TF(model, mma, m, n_output=1, activationFxn='relu').predict(variables)

# Define the GEKKO objective function
m.Maximize(pred_Q_factor)


# Variable options
Freq.STATUS = 0
Do_1.STATUS = 0
Do_2.STATUS = 0
t1.STATUS = 0
t2.STATUS = 0

m.options.SOLVER = 1  # APOPT in MINLP
m.options.IMODE = 2  # Steady-state parameter estimation mode
m.solve(debug=0, disp=True)
m.open_folder()  # use this to look at infeasibilities.txt
    
# Print the results
params_max_Q = []
print("\nOptimized design:")
for i in range(len(variables)):
    print(f'\t{features[i]}: {variables[i].value[0]: .3f}')
    params_max_Q.append(variables[i].value)
params_max_Q = np.array(params_max_Q).reshape(1, len(variables))
print(f"Maximized Q_factor: {-m.options.OBJFCNVAL}")
print(f"Maximized Q_factor: {model.predict(params_max_Q)[0][0]: .3f}")
print('Gekko Solvetime:', m.options.SOLVETIME, 'sec')
import time
min_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(m.options.SOLVETIME))
print('Gekko Solvetime:', min_time)


## SOLUTION ##
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 1.0.3
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :           97
   Constants    :            0
   Variables    :          309
   Intermediates:           98
   Connections  :          291
   Equations    :          301
   Residuals    :          203
 
 Number of state variables:            498
 Number of total equations: -          396
 Number of slack variables: -            5
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :             97
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Model Parameter Estimation with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:      0.43 NLPi:   34 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    0 Obj: -1.72E+05 Gap:  0.00E+00
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   0.440399999999499      sec
 Objective      :   -172228.826336312     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
 


Optimized design:
    Freq [MHz]:  13.560
    Do_1 [mm]:  200.000
    Do_2 [mm]:  200.000
    Gap_Distance [mm]:  5.000
    Pitch_1 [mm]:  3.039
    Pitch_2 [mm]:  4.433
    Turns:  10.000
    Width_1 [mm]:  6.229
    Width_2 [mm]:  5.000
    Di_1 [mm]:  50.000
    Di_2 [mm]:  50.000
    Thickness_1 [mm]:  0.500
    Thickness_2 [mm]:  0.500
Maximized Q_factor: 172228.82634
WARNING:tensorflow:6 out of the last 6 calls to <function TensorFlowTrainer.make_predict_function.<locals>.one_step_on_data_distributed at 0x175d93370> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has reduce_retracing=True option that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
[1m1/1[0m [32m━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━[0m[37m[0m [1m0s[0m 41ms/step
Maximized Q_factor:  783.136
Gekko Solvetime: 0.4404 sec
Gekko Solvetime: 00:00:00


2. Now, I want to add a more strict constraint:

However, the gekko cannot solve this problem with this constraint. I would like to know how to debug it. Please let me know if you know anything.
The code is shown below:
## 2nd CODE ##
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from gekko import GEKKO
from gekko.ML import Gekko_NN_TF, CustomMinMaxGekkoScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# Q-factor prediction from trained TF model
model_path = 'model_path'
model = load_model(model_path)

# CSV file reading
data_path = 'datapath'
data = pd.read_csv(data_path)

# Define output feature of the model
target = ['Q_factor']
# Basically, the input features are [Freq, Do_1, Do_2, d, p1, p2, N, w1, w2, Di_1, Di_2, t1, t2]
features = [col for col in data.columns if col not in target]

# Find max/min of scaler for Gekko_NN_TF parameters
s = CustomMinMaxGekkoScaler(data, features, target)
mma = s.minMaxValues()

# Initialize GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# Design Constants
epsilon = m.Const(value=8.854e-12, name='epsilon')
epsilon_0 = m.Const(value=1.000, name='epsilon_0')
mu = m.Const(value=1.2566e-6, name='mu')

# Design Requirements
freq_const = 13.56
Do_const = 200
sys_thickness = 200
copper_thickness = 0.5

# Define variables with bounds
Freq = m.FV(value=freq_const, lb=1, ub=30,name='Freq')
Do_1 = m.FV(value=Do_const, lb=100, ub=200,name='Do_1')
Do_2 = m.FV(value=Do_const, lb=100, ub=200,name='Do_2')
p1 = m.Var(value=7.06, lb=1, ub=30,name='p1')
p2 = m.Var(value=5.46, lb=1, ub=30,name='p2')
t1 = m.FV(value=copper_thickness, lb=0.5, ub=2,name='t1')
t2 = m.FV(value=copper_thickness, lb=0.5, ub=2,name='t2')
d = m.Var(value=4.38, lb=2, ub=10,name='d')
N = m.Var(value=4, lb=2, ub=10, integer=True,name='N')
w1 = m.Var(value=13.87, lb=5, ub=50,name='w1')
w2 = m.Var(value=15.06, lb=5, ub=50,name='w2')
Di_1 = m.Var(value=50, lb=5, ub=100,name='Di_1')
Di_2 = m.Var(value=50, lb=5, ub=100,name='Di_2')


# Average of some variables for C_coil and L_coil equation
Do = m.Intermediate((Do_1+Do_2)/2, name='Do')
Di = m.Intermediate((Di_1+Di_2)/2, name='Di')
w = m.Intermediate((w1 + w2) / 2, name='avg_w')
t = m.Intermediate((t1 + t2) / 2, name='avg_t')

# Define intermediates variables (reduce model complexity)
C_coil = m.Intermediate(epsilon * epsilon_0 * np.pi * w * 1e-3 * N * (Do + Di) * 1e-3 / (2 * d * 1e-3) * (1 + d / (np.pi * w) * m.log(2 * d / (np.pi * w)) 
                                                                                                          + d / (np.pi * w) * m.log(1 + 2 * d / (np.pi * w) + 2 * m.sqrt((t / d) + (t / d) ** 2))), name='C_coil')
L_coil = m.Intermediate(mu * (N ** 2) * (Do + Di) * 1e-3 / 4 * m.log(2.46 * (Do + Di) / (Do - Di) + 0.2 * ((Do - Di) / (Do + Di)) ** 2), name='L_coil')
resonant_freq = m.Intermediate(1/(2*np.pi*m.sqrt(L_coil*C_coil)), name='resonant_Freq')

# Define constraints
m.Equation(Di_1 == Di_2)
m.Equation(Di_1 <= Do_const)
m.Equation(Di_2 <= Do_const)
m.Equation(t1 + t2 + d <= sys_thickness)
m.Equation(p1 == (Do_1 - Di_1 - (3 * np.pi * N + 4 * np.pi - 1) / (2 * np.pi) * w1) * 2 * np.pi / (3 * np.pi * N - 1))
m.Equation(p2 == (Do_2 - Di_2 - (3 * np.pi * N + 4 * np.pi - 1) / (2 * np.pi) * w2) * 2 * np.pi / (3 * np.pi * N - 1))
m.Equation(p1 <= w1)
m.Equation(p2 <= w2)
## Added constraint
m.Equation(resonant_freq <= (Freq+0.1*Freq)*1e6)
m.Equation(resonant_freq >= (Freq-0.1*Freq)*1e6)

# Define all variables for prediction
variables = [Freq, Do_1, Do_2, d, p1, p2, N, w1, w2, Di_1, Di_2, t1, t2]

# Define model from Tensorflow/Keras trained model
pred_Q_factor = m.Param(Gekko_NN_TF(model, mma, m, n_output=1, activationFxn='relu').predict(variables), lb=0, ub=2000, name='pred_Q_factor')

# Define the GEKKO objective function
m.Maximize(pred_Q_factor)

# Variable options
Freq.STATUS = 0
Do_1.STATUS = 0
Do_2.STATUS = 0
t1.STATUS = 0
t2.STATUS = 0

m.options.SOLVER = 1  # APOPT in MINLP
m.solver_options = [
    'minlp_maximum_iterations 100', 
    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 100', 
    'minlp_as_nlp 0', 
    'nlp_maximum_iterations 50', 
    'minlp_branch_method 1', 
    'minlp_print_level 8',  
    'minlp_integer_tol 1e-4', 
    'minlp_gap_tol 0.001'
]
m.options.IMODE = 2  # Steady-state parameter estimation mode
m.solve(debug=0, disp=True)

m.open_folder()  # use this to look at infeasibilities.txt
    
# Print the results
params_max_Q = []
print("\nOptimized design:")
for i in range(len(variables)):
    print(f'\t{features[i]}: {variables[i].value[0]: .3f}')
    params_max_Q.append(variables[i].value)
params_max_Q = np.array(params_max_Q).reshape(1, len(variables))
print(f"Maximized Q_factor: {-m.options.OBJFCNVAL}")
print(f"Maximized Q_factor: {model.predict(params_max_Q)[0][0]: .3f}")
print('Gekko Solvetime:', m.options.SOLVETIME, 'sec')

**It shows **Warning: no more possible trial points and no integer solution** and @error: Solution Not Found.
This one's result is:
**
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 1.0.3
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :           97
   Constants    :            3
   Variables    :          312
   Intermediates:          105
   Connections  :          291
   Equations    :          310
   Residuals    :          205
 
 Number of state variables:            500
 Number of total equations: -          398
 Number of slack variables: -            7
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :             95
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Model Parameter Estimation with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I: -9 Tm:      1.72 NLPi:   51 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    0 Obj:  0.00E+00 Gap:       NaN
 **Warning: no more possible trial points and no integer solution**
 Maximum iterations
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :    1.74070000000211      sec
 Objective      :    97000.0000000000     
 Unsuccessful with error code            0
 ---------------------------------------------------
 
 Creating file: infeasibilities.txt
 @error: Solution Not Found


Optimized design:
    Freq [MHz]:  13.560
    Do_1 [mm]:  200.000
    Do_2 [mm]:  200.000
    Gap_Distance [mm]:  2.000
    Pitch_1 [mm]:  1.000
    Pitch_2 [mm]:  1.000
    Turns:  4.000
    Width_1 [mm]:  13.870
    Width_2 [mm]:  15.060
    Di_1 [mm]:  50.000
    Di_2 [mm]:  50.000
    Thickness_1 [mm]:  0.500
    Thickness_2 [mm]:  0.500
Maximized Q_factor: -97000.0
[1m1/1[0m [32m━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━[0m[37m[0m [1m0s[0m 46ms/step
Maximized Q_factor:  902.816
Gekko Solvetime: 1.7407 sec
Gekko Solvetime: 00:00:01


I hopefully want to get the highest pred_Q_factor and other parameter values.
Can you let me know what is the problem here? and How can I debug this?

everyone.
I changed all of the variable types from m.Var() to m.FV(). Also, Freq, Do_1, Do_2, t1, and t2 are fixed to a specific value.
# Design Requirements
freq_const = 13.56
Do_const = 200
sys_thickness = 20
copper_thickness = 0.5

# Define variables with bounds
## Fixed variables
Freq = m.FV(value=freq_const, lb=1, ub=30,name='Freq')
Do_1 = m.FV(value=Do_const, lb=100, ub=200,name='Do_1')
Do_2 = m.FV(value=Do_const, lb=100, ub=200,name='Do_2')
t1 = m.FV(value=copper_thickness, lb=0.5, ub=2,name='t1')
t2 = m.FV(value=copper_thickness, lb=0.5, ub=2,name='t2')
## Non-fixed variables
p1 = m.FV(value=1, lb=1, ub=15,name='p1')
p2 = m.FV(value=1, lb=1, ub=15,name='p2')
d = m.FV(value=2, lb=2, ub=5,name='d')
N = m.FV(value=4, lb=2, ub=10, integer=True, name='N')
w1 = m.FV(value=13.87, lb=5, ub=20,name='w1')
w2 = m.FV(value=15.06, lb=5, ub=20,name='w2')
Di_1 = m.FV(value=50, lb=5, ub=50,name='Di_1')
Di_2 = m.FV(value=50, lb=5, ub=50,name='Di_2')

# Variable options (0=fixed, 1=varied)
Freq.STATUS = 0
Do_1.STATUS = 0
Do_2.STATUS = 0
t1.STATUS = 0
t2.STATUS = 0
p1.STATUS = 1
p2.STATUS = 1
d.STATUS = 1
N.STATUS = 1
Di_1.STATUS = 1
Di_2.STATUS = 1
w1.STATUS = 1
w2.STATUS = 1

Also, I removed unnecessary m.Intermediate() and put it directly to the Equation.
# Average of some variables for C_coil and L_coil equation
Do = (Do_1+Do_2)/2
Di = (Di_1+Di_2)/2
w = (w1 + w2) / 2
t = (t1 + t2) / 2

Moreover, I changed the variable to only the normal constant variable not GEKKO.FV() in the most important constraint in this problem:
m.Equation(resonant_freq <= (Freq+0.02*Freq)*1e6)
m.Equation(resonant_freq >= (Freq-0.02*Freq)*1e6)

to:
m.Equation(resonant_freq <= (freq_const+0.02*freq_const)*1e6)
m.Equation(resonant_freq >= (freq_const-0.02*freq_const)*1e6)

I also restricted the objective function between 900 and 2000:
# Define all variables for prediction
variables = [Freq, Do_1, Do_2, d, p1, p2, N, w1, w2, Di_1, Di_2, t1, t2]

# Define model from Tensorflow/Keras trained model
# pred_Q_factor = Gekko_NN_TF(model, mma, m, n_output=1, activationFxn='relu').predict(variables)
pred_Q_factor = m.Param(Gekko_NN_TF(model, mma, m, n_output=1, activationFxn='relu').predict(variables), lb=900, ub=2000, name='pred_Q_factor')

# Define the GEKKO objective function
m.Maximize(pred_Q_factor)

m.options.SOLVER = 1  # APOPT in MINLP
m.solver_options = [
    'minlp_maximum_iterations 10000', 
    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 10000', 
    'minlp_as_nlp 0', 
    'nlp_maximum_iterations 10000', 
    'minlp_branch_method 1', 
    'minlp_print_level 8',  
    'minlp_integer_tol 1e-4', 
    'minlp_gap_tol 0.001'
]
m.options.IMODE = 2  # Steady-state parameter estimation mode
m.solve(debug=0, disp=True)

Therefore, I can solve the problem. The result is shown below:
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 1.0.3
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :           97
   Constants    :            3
   Variables    :          312
   Intermediates:          101
   Connections  :          291
   Equations    :          306
   Residuals    :          205
 
 Number of state variables:            500
 Number of total equations: -          398
 Number of slack variables: -            7
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :             95
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Model Parameter Estimation with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:      3.53 NLPi:   94 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    2 Obj: -9.00E+02 Gap:       NaN
Iter:     2 I: -1 Tm:      0.19 NLPi:    3 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    1 Obj: -9.00E+02 Gap:       NaN
Iter:     3 I:  0 Tm:      0.53 NLPi:   18 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    2 Obj: -9.00E+02 Gap:       NaN
Iter:     4 I:  0 Tm:      0.50 NLPi:   17 Dpth:    2 Lvs:    1 Obj: -9.00E+02 Gap:       NaN
Iter:     5 I:  0 Tm:      0.20 NLPi:    9 Dpth:    2 Lvs:    2 Obj: -9.00E+02 Gap:       NaN
--Integer Solution:  -9.00E+02 Lowest Leaf:  -9.00E+02 Gap:   0.00E+00
Iter:     6 I:  0 Tm:      0.05 NLPi:    3 Dpth:    3 Lvs:    2 Obj: -9.00E+02 Gap:  0.00E+00
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :    5.01840000000084      sec
 Objective      :   -900.000000000000     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
 


Optimized design:
    Freq [MHz]:  13.560
    Do_1 [mm]:  200.000
    Do_2 [mm]:  200.000
    Gap_Distance [mm]:  3.182
    Pitch_1 [mm]:  6.706
    Pitch_2 [mm]:  4.953
    Turns:  5.000
    Width_1 [mm]:  13.100
    Width_2 [mm]:  14.478
    Di_1 [mm]:  28.408
    Di_2 [mm]:  28.408
    Thickness_1 [mm]:  0.500
    Thickness_2 [mm]:  0.500
Maximized Q_factor: 900.0
1/1 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 30ms/step
Maximized Q_factor:  785.436
Gekko Solvetime: 5.0184 sec
Gekko Solvetime: 00:00:05

This result can only succeed when I mark the lower bound lb=900, ub=2000 in pred_Q_factor. It seems like it stop find the solution at the minimized lower bound (=900).
I understand that the maximization problem in GEKKO will switch to minimization. Is there anything I can do to make it maximal?

One reason that it may not be able to find a solution is that the FV values are not allowed to change because STATUS=0. Try setting the STATUS=1 to allow those FV values to be changed by the optimizer.
Freq.STATUS = 1
Do_1.STATUS = 1
Do_2.STATUS = 1
t1.STATUS = 1
t2.STATUS = 1

The value of N is different for every data row and determined by the optimizer.
N = m.Var(value=4, lb=2, ub=10, integer=True,name='N')

If only one N value should be determined, then switch it to an FV type. If the problem is still infeasible, try setting the bounds on Freq to a wider limit until the problem solves successfully such as:
m.Equation(resonant_freq <= (Freq+0.1*Freq)*1e8)
m.Equation(resonant_freq >= (Freq-0.1*Freq)*1e8)

If the optimized objective function is very high, it may be that the optimizer is finding a local optimum with the neural network model. Gekko always switches to a minimization problem by taking the negative of a maximization problem. The maximized objective of Q_factor=172228.82634 in the successful solution is very high. The output of the second isn't a feasible solution so the results are not converged to satisfy the inequality and/or equality constraints. As such, the solution can't be trusted for the failed case.

Thank you so much, John! I understand that the results do not converge in the second running operation. However, I would like to fix Freq, Do_1, Do_2, t1, and t2. That's why I set them to be 0:
Freq.STATUS = 0
Do_1.STATUS = 0
Do_2.STATUS = 0
t1.STATUS = 0
t2.STATUS = 0.
Also, I am planning to loose the resonant_freq constraint.
